# How to add js object as php array to a php file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm making tools in NodeJs to generate PHP classes.

My original PHP files that im trying to generate in node are something like this:

```
class myBlock extends bp_blocks {
    function __construct() {
        $this->id = "faq";
        $this->name = "FAQ";
    }
    function define() {
        field_group(
            array(
                'key' => '4ac436aa4400',
                'type' => 'accordion',
            ),
            array(
                'key' => '4ac436aa4401',
                'type' => 'text',
            ),
        )
    }
}
```

S I made boilerplate file like this:

```
class {#name#} extends bp_blocks {
    function __construct() {
        $this->id = {#name#};
        $this->name = {#title#};
    }
    function define() {
        field_group(
            {#fields#}
        )
    }
}
```

and use fs read to read the file and replace my tags with variables in js

```
fs.readFile("inc/blockClass.php", "utf8", function(err, data) {

    data = data.replace(/{#name#}/g, args.name)
    data = data.replace(/{#title#}/g, group.title )
    data = data.replace(/{#description#}/g, group.description )

});
```

For the fields, I have a js array that looks like this:

```
fields: [
    {
        key: 'field_5eee103ed5ba1',
        label: 'headline',
        name: 'headline',
        type: 'text',
    },
    {
        key: 'field_5eee103ed5ba2',
        label: 'Extra padding',
        name: 'padding',
        type: 'true_false',
    }
],
```

Now the question:

How do I replace {#fields#} with my js field object?
I understand that I need to convert a js object to PHP array in Nodejs, but how or is there any libraries I can use?

Comment: you can use ajax request to send your fields to the PHP file?

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate over your `fields`-array and manually build up the `php` arrays.

Note that if you have to deal with other datatype than `string` you will need to add some more code to handle those, but this should give you a start:

```js
const fields = [{
        key: 'field_5eee103ed5ba1',
        label: 'headline',
        name: 'headline',
        type: 'text',
    },
    {
        key: 'field_5eee103ed5ba2',
        label: 'Extra padding',
        name: 'padding',
        type: 'true_false',
    }
];


function buildPhpArraysFromJson(fields) {

    let res = "";

    for (const field of fields) {
        res += 'array('
        for (const key of Object.keys(field)) {
            res += `'${key}' => '${field[key]}',`
        }
        res = res.slice(0, -1);
        res += '),'
    }

    return res.slice(0, -1);
}

console.log(buildPhpArraysFromJson(fields))
```